# Alsa виртуальный микрофон на Android

Tags: android, linux, alsa, chroot

Имеется Linux chroot на Android телефоне. Очень нужно использовать alsa для воспроизведения/записи звука. Для этого написана небольшая программа, использующая Opensles функционал и принимающая/отдающая звуковые потоки через два fifo. Для её задействования использую следующий .asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm {
        type plug
        slave {
            pcm {
                type file
                file "/run/opensles_playback"
                slave.pcm null
                format raw
            }
            rate 44100
            format s16_le
            channels 2
        }
    }
    capture.pcm {
        type plug
        slave {
            pcm {
                type file
                file "/dev/null"
                infile "/run/opensles_capture"
                slave.pcm null
                format raw
            }
            rate 44100
            format s16_le
            channels 1
        }
    }
}
```

где в /run эти fifo.
Воспроизведение работает хорошо, а запись нет - быстро создаётся большой файл нулевого содержимого.
В интернете я видел советы, что для capture pcm в качестве slave pcm нельзя использовать null, а надо реальную hw карту. Но на устройстве нет ни одной hw карты.
Кто что может посоветовать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решил свою проблемму пропатчив alsa-lib pcm_file.c. Работает и воспроизведение и запись. Результаты можно найти здесь https://github.com/PavelAtr/opensles-alsa.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).